# GetWeeklySchedule directive not being sent by Amazon

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alex

I have my own nodejs alexa interface with AWS/skill and I've made a thermostat. I can't figure out how to get alexa to send the GetWeeklySchedule directive. This is working and I get back setpoint, currrent temperature, and Controlled BY Schedule in the Alexa App. I cannot get the option to change the schedule in the Alexa App

My discovery response:

```json
{
    endpointId: endpointId,
    manufacturerName: 'Me',
    description: description,
    friendlyName: friendlyName,
    displayCategories: ["THERMOSTAT"],
    cookie: {},
    capabilities:
    [
      {
        interface: 'Alexa.ThermostatController',
        version: '3.1',
        type: 'AlexaInterface',
        properties: {
          supported: [
            {
              name: 'targetSetpoint'
            },
            {
              name: 'thermostatMode'
            }
          ],
          proactivelyReported: false,
          retrievable: true
        },
        configuration:
        {
          supportedModes: ["HEAT", "OFF"],
          supportsScheduling: true
        }
      },
      {
        type: 'AlexaInterface',
        interface: 'Alexa.TemperatureSensor',
        version: '3',
        properties: {
          supported: [
            {
              name: 'temperature'
            }
          ],
          proactivelyReported: false,
          retrievable: true
        },
      },
      {
        type: "AlexaInterface",
        interface: "Alexa.ThermostatController.Schedule",
        version: "3.2",
        properties: {
          supported: [
            {
              name: "scheduleEnabled"
            }
          ],
          proactivelyReported: false,
          retrievable: true
        },
        configuration: {
          supportedFanModes: ["AUTO"],
          supportsAdaptiveRecovery: false
        }
      },
      {
        type: 'AlexaInterface',
        interface: 'Alexa',
        version: '3'
      }
    ]
  }
```

My ReportState response:

```json
{
  namespace: 'Alexa.ThermostatController',
  name: 'thermostatMode',
  value: info.deviceMode,
  timeOfSample: new Date().toISOString(),
  uncertaintyInMilliseconds: 500
}
{
  namespace: 'Alexa.ThermostatController',
  name: 'targetSetpoint',
  value:
  {
    value: info.deviceSetPoint,
    scale: 'FAHRENHEIT'
  },
  timeOfSample: new Date().toISOString(),
  uncertaintyInMilliseconds: 500
}
{
  namespace: 'Alexa.TemperatureSensor',
  name: 'temperature',
  value:
  {
    value: info.deviceTemperature,
    scale: 'FAHRENHEIT'
  },
  timeOfSample: new Date().toISOString(),
  uncertaintyInMilliseconds: 500
}
{
  namespace: 'Alexa.ThermostatController.Schedule',
  name: 'adaptiveRecoveryEnabled',
  value: false,
  timeOfSample: new Date().toISOString(),
  uncertaintyInMilliseconds: 500
}
{
  namespace: 'Alexa.ThermostatController.Schedule',
  name: 'scheduleEnabled',
  value: true,
  timeOfSample: new Date().toISOString(),
  uncertaintyInMilliseconds: 500
}
```

Comment: Can you please add syntax highlighting to your code blocks? You can see [/editing-help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for how to do so.

Comment: Ca you describe what is working, what is not working? "I can't figure out how to get alexa to send the GetWeeklySchedule directive. This is working and I get back setpoint, currrent temperature, and Controlled BY Schedule in the Alexa App."

Comment: I cannot figure out how to retrieve or set the schedule itself. The days and times, etc...

Answer (score 0):

I have checked our internal team and confirmed that this function can't be used by third party developers at this point. We will update our documents.

Comment: Lol, works no problem for using the Amazon thermostat, so the api must exist. Also, almost 1 year later?? Good thing that I developed my thermostat for use on Google and Apple! Is Amazon giving up on the Smart Home market?

Comment: I meant GetWeeklySchedule under Alexa.ThermostatController.Schedule. I am still checking what can be used under ThermostatController.Scheudle but we will update the tech doc accordingly. You can still use Alexa.ThermostatController. ThermostatController and ThermostatController.Schedule are different interface.

Comment: I understand they are different interfaces. What I don't understand is how Amazon can expect anyone to develop a thermostat that doesn't use a weekly schedule.  Good thing that the switch interface has the ability to turn on and off! I honestly don't see any difference when it comes to such an oversight for a thermostat. I would appreciate you passing on to your dev dept this strange anomaly.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I am working with internal team if we can make it public. It might take time but I will update here once I get some updates.